# Error: "You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable." in my Auth Interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular8, angular-http-interceptors

I want to intercept every request to api and check the status code so that it can display a message or redirect to a specific component, but it is giving the following error:

> main.js:1580 TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an >Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.at subscribeTo (vendor.js:179688)at subscribeToResult(vendor.js:179824) at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (vendor.js:175271) at mergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (vendor.js:175265) at MergeMapSubscriber._next (vendor.js:175248)
>   at MergeMapSubscriber.next (vendor.js:170316) at Observable._subscribe (vendor.js:172287)
>   at Observable._trySubscribe (vendor.js:169772) at Observable.subscribe (vendor.js:169758)
>   at MergeMapOperator.call (vendor.js:175233)

This is my **AuthInterceptor:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators'; 
import { CommonService } from '../common.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private common: CommonService,
    private router: Router,
    private auth: AuthenticationService
  ) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.headers.get('No-Auth') === 'True') {
      return next.handle(req.clone());
    }
    // To attach header on every request
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser') != null) {
      const clonedreq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
      });
      return next.handle(clonedreq).pipe(tap(
        succ => { },
        err => {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          } else if (err.status === 403) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/Forbidden');
          } else if (err.status === 400) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/error404');
          }
        }
      ));
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }
  }
}
```

I can't figure out the line or block which is causing it, as it is not written any where in the error. The project is compiled just fine.
this error is shown in almost every page of the project where a request is sent to WEB Api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the else block you are missing the return statement. 
Add 
`return next.handle(req.clone());` in else block when `localStorage.getItem('currentUser')` is null

Comment: This is probably because your web service output is not return  observable value

Comment: Mukund your answer removed the error but it is not intercepting the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Rishabh, others do link this error with the existence of 'interceptors', this could very well be the case. However, today I got the exact same TypeError. My app, currently still in development, does not make use of 'interceptors' (may be in the future who knows). It's an Angular app currently up-to-data (version 9.0.2) connection to an API (functions firebase). I was implementing a new components (crud) 'contractors' on which I decided to make use of 'angular-in-memory-web-api' prior storing data at the backend

As soon as I had implemented the module 'InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(ContractorData)' in the 'imports' section of the App.Module, I noticed while retrieving another entity I suddenly could not reach anymore the API noticing in the browser console:

ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. * You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

So, my hypothesis is: implementing the ImMemoryWebApiModule interfers (in my case) the HttpClient process in such a way, it removes or deletes information on the request sending to the api.

See screenshot[image]

Hopefully, this a little help you to investigate you problem!